# Switching buttons onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to switch buttons out onclick. So the scenario is a user has a window up with information and the user then clicks the delete button to get rid of something. After the delete option I would like the delete button to switch to an "OK" button where if the user clicks it the window closes.

Comment: Ok, where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I usually avoid doing other peoples' homework...

```
<style>
.button-text.hidden {display: none;}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.button-text').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
</script>

<button>
    <span class="button-text">Text One</span>
    <span class="button-text hidden">Text Two</span>
</button>
```

You'll need to customize to suit. You may not want a true toggle. You could also do a simple text replacement:

```
<button>Text</button>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).text('My New Text');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have another button that has text OK and closes the item. Upon deletion, you can hide or remove the delete button.

Alternately you can change the button text upon deletion.
Then when the button is clicked, you need to check if the button's text is Delete or OK.
Then if it is OK then close whatever you need to close.

Without code, hard to provide example.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. have two button, delete and ok.
   When the user loads the page the delete button is visible, when they click delete

   $('#deleteButton').hide();
   $('#okButton;).show();

of

```
$('#deleteButton, #okButton')toggle();
```

or change the text of the delete button when clicked to ok

```
$('#allButton').html('ok'); // or $('#allButton').val('ok');
```

and when clicked check the html of the button

```
if($('#allButton').html() == 'ok'){
  // close
 }else
 {
   // perfom delete  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/6EB78/

HTML:

```
<p class="content">This a sample content to delete</p>
<button type="button" id="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("delete"))
    {
        $(".content").remove();
        $(this).addClass("ok").removeClass("delete").text("Ok");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Content Deleted!")
    }
});
});
```